# How can you toggle auto-locking on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, shortcuts-app, control-center

Say I'm cooking and I want to look at a recipe on my iPhone without having to worry about the iPhone dimming and locking. One way to achieve this is to go to Settings -> Display & Brightness -> Auto-Lock -> Never. However, *usually* I do want my iPhone to auto-lock – it's only when I'm cooking that this is unhelpful. If I turn off auto-locking, then I might forget to turn it back on when I'm finished. Is one of the following alternatives possible?

1. Configure the iPhone so that you can change auto-locking from the control centre. This would make it easier to spot that it was off when it should be on.
2. Create a shortcut that turns off auto-locking for a set period of time, say 1 hour, and then turns it back on after that.

Any other suggestions are also welcome.